# How to properly use the index of a map function to access an element in an array

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a JSON file as follows:

```
[
  {
    "id": "0",
    "type": "time",
    "day": "today",
    "time": "0700"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "time",
    "day": "today",
    "time": "0700"
  },
 ...
]
```

I can convert it to an array and access its properties:

```
const allAvailableTimes = availableTimesJSON.map(item => item)
console.log(allAvailableTimes[0].time) // 0700
```

If I try to access one of these properties using the index of a map function, that won't work:

```
const displayAvailableTimes = availableTimesJSON.map( (item, index) =>
       item.time === allAvailableTimes[index-1].time ? //cannot read property 'time' of undefined
               <span>2</span> 
       : <div>show item</div>
```

What I am trying to do is, if a time has already been rendered, display the number 2 to next to it:

07:00²

I am trying to do this by comparing the 'time' property of the *current* element with the 'time' property of the *previous* element.

I am mapping over the original JSON file `availableTimesJSON`, but even if I change it to the array `allAvailableTimes` (with the exact same content), it'll still return undefined

Comment: because you have `allAvailableTimes[index-1]` and for the first iteration the index would be 0 and `allAvailableTimes[-1]` is undefined for the first iteration itself thus it is returning error.

Comment: on the first iteration `[index-1]` is undefined. so before accessing your property, you need to check if `allAvailableTimes[index-1]` is defined

Comment: @japrescott I thought of doing ```if (index > 0)``` but then I'd be making this comparison at every iteration. any ideas on how to solve this in a smarter way?

Answer (score 1):

For the first iteration, index will be 0, so index - 1 will be -1, which is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an extra check of `index >= 1`.

```
const displayAvailableTimes = availableTimesJSON.map( (item, index) =>
       index >= 1 && item.time === allAvailableTimes[index-1].time ? <span>2</span> : <div>show item</div>
```

Comment: Does this check then happens at every iteration? Could it be avoided?

Comment: Yes, it will check on each iteration.
Do you want to avoid this check on each iteration?

Comment: It doesn't affect the outcome if it's still there, but I wondered if it could be avoided for the sake of performance.

Comment: I don't think that it will affect performance much. However, any attempt to avoid index >= 1 condition will create more conditions. One good way is to `availableTimesJSON.slice(1).map(...)`.